# firestore: let users update, delete only their own data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

These are my current security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /tournaments/{tournament=**} {
    allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;
    allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    allow read: if true;
  }
  }
}
```

Everything is working, only updating or deleting does not work due to "Missing or insufficient permissions"

Here is my code for that

```
            mDocRef
                .update(key, score)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error updating document", e);
                    }
                });
```

mDocRef refers to a document with a path of "tournaments/tournamentID/aColletion/aDocument"

Here is the code to create mDocRef:

```
            mTournamentDocRef = mTournamentColRef.document();
            mDocRef = mTournamentDocRef.collection("aCollection").document();
```

Some things to note:

- the user is during the whole process signed in through firebase
- I tried using .where("author", "==", user.uid) but got an "cannot resolve method" error

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the ID of the firebase user to each document that is created to get the wanted results

```
 tournamentData.put("author", user.getUid());
 data.put("author", user.getUid());
```

Answer (score 3):

I checked the documentation, those are the rules you are looking for:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
  allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

And the documentation link as a reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?authuser=0